# How to extract out a scalar multiplier?

Tags: symbolic

I'm trying to make a custom multiplication operation, which would be distributive, as well as associative with normal multiplication by scalar. Using `Distribute` I can get the distributive transformation:

```
Distribute[dot[235 vec[i] + vec[j], vec[k] + vec[l]]]
```

> dot[235 vec[i], vec[k]] + dot[235 vec[i], vec[l]] + 
>    dot[vec[j], vec[k]] + dot[vec[j], vec[l]]

Here `dot` is only defined via `dot[vec[i_],vec[j_]]:=...`.

Now I need to transform these `dot[235 vec[i], vec[k]]`-like items into `235 dot[vec[i], vec[k]]`. How can I do this?

Comment: You should add a rule that factors out constants: `dot[n_?NumericQ c_, d_] := n dot[c,d]`.  Another alternative taking advantage of the fact that your have your own `vec` datatype is `dot[n_ c_vec, d_vec] := n dot[c,d]`.  Finally, you might be interested in setting `SetAttributes[dot, Orderless]` *before* the mentioned rules so that it works on the second argument also, automatically sort its arguments, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Code.*

This will extract the factors from the arguments of `dot` that do not have head `vec`.

```
dot[(a : Except[_vec, _]) v1_vec, v2_vec] := a dot[v1, v2];

dot[v1_vec, (b : Except[_vec, _]) v2_vec] := b dot[v1, v2];

dot[(a : Except[_vec, _]) v1_vec, (b : Except[_vec, _]) v2_vec] := a b dot[v1, v2];
```

*Usage.*

```
dot[235 vec[i], vec[k]]
(* 235 dot[vec[i], vec[k]] *)

dot[vec[i], n vec[k]]
(* n dot[vec[i], vec[k]] *)

dot[235 vec[i], n vec[k]]
(* 235 n dot[vec[i], vec[k]] *)
```

Comment: Great. And a third one should be with both `a` and `b`.

Comment: Yes, I will add this to the code for completeness.